# how i can set null values in left join in presto with the max values from the right joined table

Tags: sql, presto, row-number

I need to set the null value causes left join with the values of records that match max(column_value) in the group , so i have tow table :

the first one is :

```
discount_id | sequence | groupid | ruleid |  tbl_dt
-------------+----------+---------+--------+----------
        1111 |        1 |     141 |   1175 | 20190924
        1111 |        5 |     107 |   1204 | 20190924
        1111 |        4 |     132 |   1199 | 20190924
        1111 |        6 |     150 |   1887 | 20190924
```

the second one is :

```
 subsid  | discount_id
---------+-------------
 3087048 |        1111
 3087047 |        1111
 3087050 |        1111
 3087045 |        1111
 3087046 |        1111
 3087044 |        1111
 3087049 |        1111
 3087043 |        1111
```

what i was trying to do is to combain the second table raw by raw with the first one so the my output is :

```
subsid  | discount_id | sequence | groupid | ruleid
---------+-------------+----------+---------+--------
 3087043 |        1111 |        5 |     107 |   1204
 3087043 |        1111 |        6 |     150 |   1887
 3087043 |        1111 |        4 |     132 |   1199
 3087043 |        1111 |        1 |     141 |   1175
 3087044 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087045 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087046 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087047 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087048 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087049 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
 3087050 |        1111 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL
```

the code i used to produce above table is  :

```
 insert into work.disc_plan select SubsID , MSISDN , EppAcc, User_Name ,
 Bill_Cycle, Tariff , Pack ,Discount_Qual_ID ,a.Discount_ID , Qualification_Type,Discount_Desc,Sequence,GroupID,RuleID,20190924
 from ((select *, row_number() over (partition by Discount_ID order by subsid ) as seqnum from work.subs_disc where tbl_dt=20190924 order by Discount_ID) a 
 left join (select *, row_number() over (partition by Discount_ID order by sequence ) as seqnum from work.rules where tbl_dt=20190924  ) b 
 on a.Discount_ID=b.Discount_ID and  a.seqnum=b.seqnum  ) ;
```

what i need now to fill NULL values that causes by left join by the value of records of max(sequence)

so my exepted otuput should by like this :

```
subsid  | discount_id | sequence | groupid | ruleid
---------+-------------+----------+---------+--------
 3087043 |        1111 |        5 |     107 |   1204
 3087043 |        1111 |        6 |     150 |   1887
 3087043 |        1111 |        4 |     132 |   1199
 3087043 |        1111 |        1 |     141 |   1175
 3087044 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087045 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087046 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087047 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087048 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087049 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
 3087050 |        1111 |      6   |     150 |   1887
```

any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this coalesce(Sequence, MAX(a.Sequence)) in the outer select part.